# How do I fetch HealthKit workout activity type?

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

I am trying to fetch the activity type (Running, Streching etc.) of an `HKWorkout` but I haven't found a good solution. I wrote a function to fetch the Temperature during workout but I can't get a proper working function to get the activity type. Is it possible to fetch the activity type similar to this?

```
func getWorkoutWeather(workout: HKWorkout) -> Double {
    if let metadata = workout.metadata {
        if let  mataTemperature = metadata[HKMetadataKeyWeatherTemperature] {
            if let quantityTemperature = mataTemperature as? HKQuantity {
                let celsius = quantityTemperature.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.degreeCelsius())
                print(celsius)
                return celsius
            }
        }
    }
    return 0
}
```

Comment: Is `workout.workoutActivityType` what you're looking for? Returns a `HKActivityWorkoutType` enumeration https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkworkoutactivitytype

Comment: Yes, that is what I’m looking for